# Recyclerview animation issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have a Recyclerview the items of which contain icons that I am trying to rotate by specific degrees (counter clockwise). Problem is some of the icons do not rotate at all, or after I scroll (or when the activity resumes) they are set back to their initial position. As seen in the image below, the first 3 arrows have not been rotated at all, while the 4th arrow is pointing correctly.
Below is the custom adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomListAdapter.TransportationViewHolder> {

Context ctx;
ArrayList<Transportation> transportationArrayList, copy;

public CustomListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Transportation> transportation) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.transportationArrayList = new ArrayList<>(transportation);
  
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TransportationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.transportation_item_layout, parent, false);
    return new CustomListAdapter.TransportationViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TransportationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Transportation transportation = transportationArrayList.get(position);
    holder.transportationFleetTypeTextView.setText(description);
    rotateHeading((float)transportation.getHeading(), holder.headingImageView);
   
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return transportationArrayList.size();
}


public static class TransportationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView transportationFleetTypeTextView;
    ImageView transportationImageView, headingImageView;

    public TransportationViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        transportationFleetTypeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.transportation_item_text);
        transportationImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.transportation_item_image);
        headingImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.heading_image);
    }

    public void clearAnimation() {
        itemView.clearAnimation();
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void rotateHeading(float rotation, ImageView imageView)
{
    AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    animSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animSet.setFillAfter(true);
    animSet.setFillEnabled(true);

    final RotateAnimation animRotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f-rotation,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    animRotate.setDuration(0);
    animRotate.setFillAfter(true);
    animSet.addAnimation(animRotate);
    imageView.startAnimation(animSet);
}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull final TransportationViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    holder.clearAnimation();
}
}
```

And below is the way I initialize the adapter (which is within a class that extends AsyncTask).

```
mainActivity.customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(mainActivity, transportationArrayList);
mainActivity.customListAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
mainActivity.customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mainActivity);
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.transportationRecyclerView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
```

[image]

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that `transportation.getHeading()` is returning the values that you think it is?

Comment: @Cheticamp yes I am sure of it. I have log messages showing those values in order to cross check

Comment: Why are you using an _AnimationSet_ with one animation and why is the duration zero?

Comment: @Cheticamp it's one animation per item (which is what I want). The duration is 0 because I don't really want to animate it I just want to have it rotate by the correct angle so my goal is not to see the animation itself but rather the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the duration is zero and you only want the result of the animation and not the animation itself, I suggest that you simplify the code by replacing the line

```
rotateHeading((float)transportation.getHeading(), holder.headingImageView);
```

with

```
holder.headingImageView.seRotation(360 = (float)transportation.getHeading())
```

and deleting all the animation code.

This change may not fix the underlying issue that you are having, but it will eliminate animation as the source of the problem.

Comment: yep that's what I ended up doing. But the question still remains what if I did want the animation to play out?

Comment: @JamesEle Good question. Maybe the issue is the zero value. If you are so inclined, you can set the duration to a non-zero value to see if it works.

Comment: that was the first thing I did and the issue still persists